# Best way to score (and create a score table) in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Imagine the following in Firebase (but with many more entries):

```
"users" : {
    "1GNdw6kJ1GdbmiOBHrA0uTnt4kh2" : {
      "countries" : [ {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "france"
      }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "spain"
      } ]
    },
    "7aaII9EkBoefI4micgdKwTFnV3E2" : {
      "countries" : [ {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "france"
      }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "russia"
      } ]
    },
    "ND9iZYJ3gfQUvjKSRaKKc8NEkAj2" : {
      "countries" : [ {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "france"
      }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "spain"
      } ]
    }
```

What would be the best way (recommended) way to handle the scoring of users based on countries they have visited?

For responsiveness purpose I don't want the scoring to be done on client side (because it would mean retrieve all users and then do the calculation).

I would like it to be done on the Database side (each time a country is changed for instance).

Thanks

Comment: Firebase doesn't have server side logic for performing calculations, so that would have to be done client side. That being said, if you have a couple thousand users, with the right Firebase structure, it would be very fast.

Comment: Thank you Jay.Do you know any Backend as a Service with interesting pricing options that would allow to do so?

Comment: There are a number of quality BaaS available but I would suggest continuing to work with Firebase - change your logic in a way that would allow a client to score themselves as they visit additional countries. Even with significant number of users, this could be accomplished fairly easily from the client side.

Comment: Alright, I get your point, thank you! By the way, I asked another question related to the implementation of your suggestion, if you can be of any help! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950246/how-to-handle-recursive-asynchronous-db-calls-that-modify-the-same-variable)